Were Imperial German cities democratic? Who governed them?
Currently researching the advent of city zoning, which originated in Germany. From Sonia Hirt's The rules of residential segregation: US housing taxonomies and their precedents I learned that German officials had the power to permit denser construction than zoning would have ordinarily permitted even in the 19th century. This strikes me as odd, given that (at least in my understanding) this power is a relatively new one for local officials in the US, in response to the 21st century housing crisis. Anyway, that long digression is just an explanation for my curiosity about the municipal level German government at that time. From Encyclopedia Britannica and Wikipedia, I gather that unlike the US, constituent states of the German empire had control over their form of government, and that at least the Free Hanseatic Cities had republican governments.

Are you only interested in the form of government on the municipal level, or also in their autonomy and the scope of jurisdiction? The question is only about the first, but your explanation also alludes to the second.

I'm interested in both. I suppose I hadn't seriously considered that material differences in municipal authority may exist, but that is an important thing to understand.

I'm far from an expert on the topic, but a few remarks that may be helpful: The status as "Freie Stadt" or "Reichsstadt" refers mostly to external relations, not so much internal affairs. If a city was under direct authority of the emperor (and not a regional duke or similar) and was allowed to manage its own affairs, it doesn't say how the city did it. If there were elections, the right to vote and/or to be voted into office was in many cases severely restricted (for example, to the local elites).

Also, the status as "Freie Stadt" or "Reichsstadt" has developed over centuries and was interpreted quite differently at different times, for different cities etc. If a city wanted to ward of meddling from a duke, it may emphasize their status as "Freie Stadt" today - while de-emphasizing that status tomorrow, if the emperor started to meddle too much. "Freie Stadt" and "Reichsstadt" are not the same, even though they are often referred to with the (technically inaccurate) term "Freie Reichsstadt". So, to answer your question, you may well need to look at a specific city at a specific time.

@HenningKockerbeck My understanding from the tag [tag:imperial-germany] is that the question is about the period 1871-1918. At that time, there were only three Reichsstädte remaining: Bremen, Hamburg and Lübeck.

Germany then was a confederation of Kingdoms and States. The role of cities would then be defined within each Kingdom. In Prussia this started in 1809 (see: When was the concept of electoral districts / constituencies with their own borders (as opposed to pre-existing towns/counties) invented? - History Stack Exchange) ...

... and envolved more during the 1860's (see: Was there a German re-urbanization plan for after WWII? - History Stack Exchange)

I am answering the question you ask in the title, i.e. what form of government the Imperial Cities of the period of the Second German Empire (1871-1918) had. Note that the form of city government in all other cities in the other states were substantially different.
At that time, there were three cities that were states of the Empire: Bremen, Hamburg and Lübeck. Their constitutions can be certainly called republican, but democratic? Rather not.
There are three legal levels to consider: the electoral principles, as described in the constitutions, the electoral procedures, as described in electoral law, and the laws of citizenship.
Citizenship
To start with the last: Only a minority of the inhabitants of the three cities were considered citizens. In Hamburg 1879, of 450,000 inhabitants only 22,000 had the right to elect the city parliament (Bürgerschaft), while 103,000 could vote for the Imperial parliament (Reichstag). As I will explain later, this was partially due to income restrictions, but the relation of the number of electors for both parliaments gives an impression how many citizens of other German states were living in Hamburg: they were certainly in the majority.
Suffrage
All three cities had an elected parliament, called Bürgerschaft. If you only look at the constitutions, they seem to be democratically elected by the citizens. But there are a number of filters to becoming an elector (not all of them apply to all cities):

being male (that one isn't even mentioned)
older than 25 years
paying taxes
not being bankrupt
not receiving aid for paupers
having sworn the city oath (Bürgereid), which might be associated
with paying a substantial fee

Curia
Also, the elections were not in any sense equal.
Bremen had divided the citizenship into eight classes that each elected their own group of representatives. Part of them (28) are representatives for outlying localities, but four of them distinguish between academics (14), merchants, Kaufmänner (42), owners of a business, Gewerbetreibende (22), and all others (44). The brackets contain the number of members elected to the total of 150.
In Hamburg, of the 160 representatives only 80 were elected in "universal, direct elections with secret vote". 40 representatives were elected by real estate owners, and 40 by notables of the city, defined as current or former

judges, commercial judges, members of the guardianship authority, civil members of the administrative authorities

"Members" of an authority were by no means all employees, but only the leading roles.
For Lübeck, I am not completely clear whether a class distinction existed for the purpose of the elections before 1905. The constitution does not mention them. Afterwards, there are four classes that elect their own representatives: inside the city 1. those that have payed taxes on a minimum income of 2000 M yearly (90), 2. all others (12), rural areas: 3. those that cultivate at least 3 ha of land or that pay taxes same as above (15), 4. all others (3).
Executive branch
Things get strange when describing the executive leadership, called Senat, with the city mayor as its head. From medieval tradition, the members of that body were elected for life-time by the already elected members. By the second half of the 19th century, the Bürgerschaft had gained some influence over who would become a member, but still the other members of the Senat had the final vote. Election for lifetime remained. Each city made sure that a majority of the members of the Senat were academics, preferably in the field of law, and a minimum number were merchants.
The rules for Senat membership elections are quite elaborate in every city, and differ in detail. But the main procedure goes like this: Both Bürgerschaft and Senat name an equal number of delegates that have the task to nominate one or more candidates. After narrowing down the field, the remaining candidates are presented to the Senat who then elects its new member.

Unless other links are provided, all the above was based on the city constitutions:

Bremen 1875; the procedure for electing the Senat is described here
Hamburg 1879
Lübeck 1875 with later changes, most notably in 1905

